# jqGrid without jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I can't find a clear answer on this. Is it possible to use [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) **without** using jQueryUI on my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the install.txt:

> In order to use jqGrid 3.5, first a UI
>   theme css file should be loaded.
>   Download the desired theme (or build a
>   custom one) from jQueryUI site
>   (www.jqueryui.com) and point in your
>   link tag in head section the path to
>   the theme css

via `http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6`

Comment: So I guess the answer would be "not exactly". You can use jqGrid without running the jqUI js file, but you have to have a valid jqUI css file.  Thanks for your help.